# how to convert a mesh to a volume

Tags: 3d, vedo

I have a mesh object which defines a 3D object and I can load it with vedo as:

```
from vedo import *
mesh = Mesh("myphantom.obj")
mesh.show()
```

What  would like to do is convert this to a 3D volume which I can reslice. Is it possible to do this with vedo. I did not see any API call to do this.

in my case, basically I want to save all visible elements as a 3D label map i.e. a binary volume/segmentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```py
from vedo import *
mesh = Mesh(dataurl + "apple.ply")
vol = mesh.binarize(spacing=(0.02,0.02,0.02))
print(vol)
vslice = vol.slice_plane(origin=(0,0,0), normal=(1,1,1)).cmap('jet')
# print(vslice.pointdata["ImageScalars"])
show(mesh, vol, vslice, N=3, axes=1)
```

[image output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RrsX.png)